# Video Output to TV is shutting down on full speed playback of video, or split screen display

Tags: video, output

I've got a client at a golf course with software that captures videos from two cameras.  One video is from down the line and the other is from straight on.  They have two physical displays, 1 computer monitor connected via VGA and a big screen TV connected via HDMI (DVI to HDMI converter).

Recently, the video card went out on this computer, so I replaced it.  Everything is working except for two instances.

1. If the user selects a 'split screen' display (showing the input from each camera side-by-side), the TV display goes black.  When you go back to another display that works, the TV briefly displays the split screen as it should have, but then switches to the new type of display selected.
2. If the user selects a previously recorded video and plays it back full speed, again the TV display goes black.  However, if you pause the video it will display fine on the TV. You can also play it in slow motion and it will display. Only full speed playback causes the issue.

I'm trying to troubleshoot this to the best of my ability before doing anything else.  I've considered buying a better video card to see if this is the problem, but I don't want to do that until I've eliminated any other possible issues.

Thanks in advance,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that everything worked fine before you replaced the video card, did the software vendor recommend a video card for this set up? if not, does the software vendor provide a list of supported video cards? Does your new card fall in this list?

I highly suspect that the replacement card has a compatibility issue with the "capture" software. Have you contacted technical support for the software vendor?

It is possible there is also a driver conflict or that when you replaced the video card you did not provide the correct driver. Assuming this is a PC running Windows, did you check the 'device manager' to see if there are any yellow or red flags?

How to check the device manager, one way. Start-->right click on 'my computer', then choose 'manage' from the drop down menu, a 2 pane window will appear, click on device manager in the left pane, look for details in the right pane.

Comment: Yes, they recommend ATI or nVidea. The new card is ATI.  I am working with them, but it's slow support (24 hour response time).  There aren't any device conflicts. I downloaded the latest driver from the manuf. website. I think I'll get a new upgraded card, a different brand ATI card and see if it works. I'll update once I get more info.

Comment: Sounds good. Am I correct that you are running Windows on a PC?

Comment: Yes, Windows Vista on a PC. The software is V1 Pro from www.V1Sports.com